# N Queens Java program stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, while-loop, infinite-loop, n-queens

I am doing an N queens problem. Right now I have the board set up so that all the queens are set up in a diagonal as so:

```
Q * *
* Q *
* * Q
```

The program works when the N size of the board is 4 and 5. But when it is size 6, it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public void solve(){

  while(d2() + d1() != 0){

  int a = (int)Math.floor((Math.random() * (gridSize - 1)) + 0);


  int temp1 = d1() + d2();
  for(int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {
        if(isQueen(row,col)){
        swapRows(a,row);}
        int temp2 = d1() + d2();
        if(temp1 < temp2){
          swapRows(row,a);}
       }
     } 
   }printSolution();}//end solve
```

D1 and D2 keep track of the number of diagonal collisions. I used Math.random() to create a random swap between two rows and check if it increases or decreases the number of collisions. Any ideas on why my method is stuck in an infinite loop when the gridSize is 6 or greater?

Thanks

Comment: Since you're getting an infinite loop, it would help if we knew what was happening within your condition (d1 and d2). Also, as I mentioned in your question yesterday, I *did* write a detailed 3 part series on this problem, with three different approaches to a solution. You may learn something about your approach if you were to read the blog posts.

Comment: Yes I saw your three methods, but it only incorporates a one dimensional array. How does your algorithm work with 2D array?

Comment: Representing the n-queens problem as a 2D array is adding more complexity to the problem than you need to. It's much easier -- and more efficient -- to represent the problem as a 1D array where each array position is a column, and the value in each position is the row. Doing so also eliminates the possibility of having multiple queens in the same column, thus reducing your computational complexity at the highest bound.

Comment: I'm sure that if you step through this with a debugger, you'll find the problem very quickly.